# Screenshot On-Screen Trigger using Flutter & Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a flutter app in which one of the features is the On-Screen Screenshot Trigger that will overlay over other apps take screenshots with a click. If anyone can help me regarding this kindly do so.
I'm attaching a screenshot of what type of trigger I'm trying to build.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaWBt.jpg)

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot

Comment: I'm not trying to capture widgets of same app. What I'm trying to build is a on-screen trigger for screenshots that will take screenshot while using other apps like instagram & twitter.